# Resize askopenfilename dialog (width) in tkinter on Linux [Python]

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, dialog, resize

I was just wondering if it's possible to resize the askopenfilename dialog in tkinter on Linux. I can't seem to find anything related to this subject. Any help would be really appreciated!